# Как подставить значение js переменной в php

Tags: php, javascript

Нужно подставить значение `this.id` для ключа `id`.
Чувствую, что намудрил, но не знаю как правильно сделать.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    ...
    if (confirm("Вы уверены?"))
        window.location = '<?=$this->createUrl('controller/action', ['id' => '<script type="text/javascript">this.id</script>']); ?>';
    ...
</script>
```

Comment: `this.id` - это значение на серверной стороне?

Comment: на клиентской. это id элемента, по которому я кликнул

Comment: тогда - никак, так как php - выполняется на сервере, а javacript - На клиенте. Максимум можно воспользоваться советом из ответа и собрать какой-нибудь шаблон, сохранить его в строку, и на клиенте вставить в нее нужное значение

Answer (score 1):

Если Вам нужно для нескольких кнопок сделать действие например удаление, то получается такой код:

```
<div class="delete" data-url-to-delete="<?=$this->createUrl('controller/action', array($id)); ?>">Удалить</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    document.querySelectorAll(".delete").forEach(function(el){
        el.addEventListener("click", function(e){
            var urlToDelete = el.getAttribute("data-url-to-delete");
            if (confirm("Вы уверены?"))
                window.location = urlToDelete;
        });
    });
</script>
```

Или же при нажатии на кнопку передавать ID, в обработчике генерировать URI и делать редирект на URI

Comment: И в каком месте тут передается нужное автору ID для формирования ссылки?

Comment: @VenZell поправил — добавил ID

Comment: Это Yiiшный метод для формирования url, в который нужно передать массив с параметрами. Поэтому вынесение их за метод не подойдет

Comment: @Mihanik71 а зачем вы отвечаете на вопросы, в котором вы не понимаете, что требуется человеку? Надо бы и попросить конкретизировать в комментарии к вопросу

Comment: Мне нужно передать `this.id` в `createUrl` таким образом: `<?=$this->createUrl('controller/action', ['id' => this.id]); ?>`. Но так я написать не могу потому, что this.id - это код на js, а все остальное - код на php.

Comment: Но Вы же можете несколько кнопок сделать. Или сначала передать this.id в PHP, а потом вызвать функцию createUrl с нужными параметрами (из $_REQUEST) и сделать редирект или сразу выполнить нужное действие

Answer (score 0):

Понял, что `js` в `php` не подставить, поэтому сделал `ajax` запрос к `controller/action`, и передал в него `id`